# Shifting list items but not the first one which is to the left of other div

Tags: css

i am trying to creatge some space in list items with say `margin-left:10px;` It works fine but it also shifts the first li.how can i achieve the thing that the first should not move while other have a gap.
Should i do margin to negitive to `ul` in order to set the first `li` or the `li` which is sticking to the left in a outer container with a fixed width to the other div.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always push the `ul` later with margins and padding cause it will save you time while setting `css` for some `lis` singularly.

Answer (score 0):

-use this:

`ul > li:first-child { margin-left:0px;`}

Answer (score 0):

Apply the margin starting from the second `<li>`, e.g.

```
li + li { margin-left: 10px; }
```

on modern browser you may also write

```
ul li:nth-child(n + 1) { margin-left: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `margin` on your `li`s and after that, reset the `margin` for the first:

```
li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: @putvane what about the third or forth li which sticks again to left.

Comment: The `:first-child` only targets the first element. So you probably have another `ul` or something. Can you show your HTML?